# Что значит префикс С в именах классах фреймворка?

Tags: yii, rules

В стандартных именах классов yii фреймворка есть префикс **С** , например:

```
CApplication
CBehavior
CComponent

и тд
```

хотелось бы знать от какого слова он произошел.

Comment: обычно это сокращение от _Class_

Comment: @Grundy подозревал тоже самое, а вы меня убедили в этом окончательно. благодарю

Comment: Это не суффикс, а префикс.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, так и надо было исправить :-)

Comment: Мне интересно, а это имеет сильное значение что там  в начале имен классов?

Comment: @Grundy более того - "суффикс-приставка"!!! Уникальный случай

Comment: поправил. долго не мог вспомнить это слово.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вы все чужие глюки собираете?

Comment: ответ на вопрос - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14438-do-not-use-c-for-prefixing-customextension-classes/

Comment: @perfect да ты такие перлы постоянно выдаешь, уже на книгу набралось)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю. а вот там понятно написано для устранения разрешения конфликтов с PHP

Comment: @Grundy не успел )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii1 появился во времена, когда в PHP не было [пространств имён](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php). С помощью префикса "C" разработчики фреймворка снизили вероятность пересечения имён классов фреймворка с именами классов сторонних библиотек и компонентов.

Объяснения в оф.документации (см. блок "Подсказка"): http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/basics.namespace#sec-5

> **Подсказка**: Так как версии PHP до 5.3.0 не поддерживают пространства имён, вы не можете создать экземпляры классов с одинаковыми именами, но различными описаниями. По этой причине все названия классов Yii-фреймворка имеют префикс 'C' (означающий 'class'), чтобы их можно было отличить от пользовательских классов. Для пользовательских классов рекомендуется использовать другие префиксы, сохранив префикс 'C' зарезервированным для Yii-фреймворка.

Comment: Уж цитату можно было и воткнуть)

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо.